# Why don't string union types work with variables?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use a type alias as a union type for 3 different strings.

This works when I set the type to a string literal, but doesn't when I try to use variables.

```
// store strings in constants
const EDIT_STATE = 'EDIT_STATE';
const EDITING_SUBMIT = 'EDITING_SUBMIT';
const EDITING_COMPLETE = 'EDITING_COMPLETE';

// this works, but means I'm repeating the literals twice
type UiState1 = 'EDIT_STATE' | 'EDITING_SUBMIT' | 'EDITING_COMPLETE';

// this is what I'm trying to do, but throws error "Cannot find name 'EDIT_STATE'"
type UiState2 = EDIT_STATE | EDITING_SUBMIT | EDITING_COMPLETE;
```

Why won't union types work with variables?

Comment: because allowing that, especially with arbitrary variables,  would require to execute the code before the compiler could typecheck the code, and not everyone consider this a good idea

Comment: but if the compiler knows the variable is a string why is that any different to using a string literal?

Comment: It's different because compiler knows that the value is a string only in easy cases. Typescript maintains conceptual distinction between values and types. If you need a type of a value you can use `typeof`, it will return  appropriate generalized type - `string` or maybe `any`  when compiler does not know it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're trying to use a value for a type.
You have two options:

(1) Create types for your values:

```
const EDIT_STATE = 'EDIT_STATE';
type EDIT_STATE = "EDIT_STATE";

const EDITING_SUBMIT = 'EDITING_SUBMIT';
type EDITING_SUBMIT = "EDITING_SUBMIT";

const EDITING_COMPLETE = 'EDITING_COMPLETE';
type EDITING_COMPLETE = "EDITING_COMPLETE";
```

(notice that you can use the same name for both the value and the type)

(2) You can use `typeof`:

```
type UiState2 = typeof EDIT_STATE | typeof EDITING_SUBMIT | typeof EDITING_COMPLETE;
```

You can read a bit more on this type/value issue here: [Declaration Merging
 - Basic Concepts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#basic-concepts)

Comment: But using the string literals also means using a value as a type, so why is it worse when I store the value in a variable? and won't using `typeof` always evaluate to `string`?

Comment: No, if you do `let a: typeof EDIT_STATE;` then the type of `a` is `"EDIT_STATE"`.  When you are creating the type alias for the string literals, you get an error saying "Cannot find name 'EDIT_STATE'", and that's because there's no such type with that name. You have a variable with that name, but not a type.